# Crystal Report: How do you add distinct values?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, distinct

For example I have:

> Supplier GroupName
>
> ID  name     value
>
> 01  chair    5,000
>
> 02  table    3,000
>
> 03  mantle   4,000
>
> 01  cabinet  5,000
>
> 02  closet   3,000

The total result should be 12,000 since the ID was repeated.

another example is this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp2Qr.jpg

the total for cash should be 75,000 based on the SOS#

Comment: do you mean show total for only distinct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Running Total which sums value, but only evaluates on change of ID and doesn't reset.

Comment: What if you change your group sort first and sort it by ID so you get all 01's together, all 02's together, etc. Then it should work, it does in my sample report.

Comment: the requirement is grouped by supplier

Comment: Then change your record sort to the id field.

Answer (score 2):

1 In the Field Explorer >> Right Click 'Running Total Fields' >> New

2 In the Create Running Total window select the choices as following:

Field to summarize: YourColumnName
Typeof summary: distinct sum

Evaluate:
For each record

Reset:
Never

Try and check if it works. I dont have crystal report but i just tried to recalled what i did earlier

Comment: there's no distinct sum for the cash value.

Comment: there's only distinct count.

Comment: @franz312 can you check if you can create formula while doing running total. In formula see if you are able to add this distinct(yourcolumnname)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

1] Order your result set on ID column. This will bring all your repeating ID's together.

2] Add one formula in the details section. In that formula write

```
if previous({Command.ID}) <> {Command.ID} then 1
else 0
```

This formula will show 1 and 0's in the details section. Lets name that formula as @test
(You can suppress it)

3] Now add one more formula in detail, say @test1. In that formula write

```
Shared numbervar num;
if {@test} = 1 then 
num:=num + {Command.Value};
num;
```

(Suppress this formula too)

4] Group header add one formula say @test2. In that formula write

```
Shared numbervar num;
num:=0;
```

5] In group footer add one formula say @test3. (This formula will be your Sum of the totals in details.i.e. your expected sum) Write below code in this formula

```
Shared numbervar num;
num;
```

This will help! Thanks!